# Why doesn't my .JSX script recognize every image in a folder which I want to mass-resize?

Tags: javascript, extendscript, photoshop-script

I have this JSX script I created but I feel like it's not checking for every file type in the `filelist` variable. Can someone take a look? It's very frustrating when I have it running and then for some reason a non-descript error message pops up and then it stops

Here is the script:

```
var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder to process"),
    fileList = inputFolder.getFiles(/\.(jpg|tif|psd|crw|cr2|nef|dcr|dc2|raw)$/i);

for(var i=0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        var doc = open(fileList[i]);
        if(doc.width !== doc.height) {
            if(doc.width > doc.height) {
                doc.resizeCanvas(doc.width, doc.width)
            } else {
                doc.resizeCanvas(doc.height, doc.height)
            }
        }
        if((doc.width && doc.height) > 1000) {
            doc.resizeImage(1000, 1000);
        } else {
            doc.resizeImage(doc.width, doc.height);
        }

    doc.save();
    doc.close();
}
```

This is the error message: [image]

Comment: Maybe unrelated to the question, but `if((doc.width && doc.height) > 1000)` seems wrong. Do you want to check if the width AND the height are both over 1000 pixels? Then it should be `doc.width > 1000 && doc.height > 1000`. If you want to check if the width OR height are over 1000 pixels (e.g. resize to 1000x1000 any image that is bigger than this) then `doc.width > 1000 || doc.height > 1000` should work.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Toribio: Script seems to work just fine except what I just said in question. I am basically resizing canvas ultimately so aspect ratio is 1:1 -- if the image is already in 1:1 aspect ratio and 1000 x 1000 or below then I leave it.

Comment: @NicholasHirras: Added error message

Comment: @Adrift It may work in this case because `((doc.width && doc.height) > 1000)` is equivalent to `(doc.height > 1000)` in Javascript. But the comparison is clearly wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see, will make the modifications, thank you

Comment: @Toribio: So instead of  `if((doc.width && doc.height) > 1000)` it should be  `if(doc.width > 1000 && doc.height) > 1000) {`? I didn't quite get the second part because I'm also resizing the canvas here.

Comment: I don't think `.getFiles` accepts a `RegExp` object, at least that is not mentioned in the documentation https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/folder-object.html#getfiles

Comment: @Toribio is correct, (doc.width && doc.height) results in a boolean value, so ((doc.width && doc.height) > 1000) is like saying if true > 1000. Unless doc.with is 0 or doc.height is 0, then it would be like saying if false > 1000

Comment: I'm sorry I'm working on this for my compnay I'm not even the owner o fthis account, what would the proper line be?

Comment: Can PayPal $5 for it im so sorry

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that the open() function is expecting a different type of argument, or perhaps addtn'l arguments that weren't provided. Perhaps the open() function needs a file path to the file to open. Perhaps each member of the fileList has this path info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Folder.getFiles()` doesn't accept `RegExp` objects, it only accepts a `string` or a `function`, beside that, it will also include `Folder` objects, you can change it to something like this to filter only files and only the file types you're interested in:

```
function filter(file) {
  return (file instanceof File && /\.(jpg|tif|psd|crw|cr2|nef|dcr|dc2|raw)$/i.test(file.name))
}
fileList = inputFolder.getFiles(filter);
```

Comment: I've always declared a `new RegExp` object and stored it as a variable for the `Folder.getFiles()` method as well as stored the `Folder` path as a `new Folder` object, for example: 
`var fileValidation = new RegExp (/\.(jpg|tif|psd|psb|png)$/i);`
`var inputFolder = new Folder("C:/your/folder/location");`
`var inputFiles = inputFolder.getFiles(fileValidation);`
`var len = inputFiles.length;`
`alert(len);`

Comment: @InternetRebel I haven't tested this (regex not working), I'm basing this on the [DOCUMENTATION](https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/folder-object.html?highlight=getfiles#getfiles), are you that in **ExtendedScript** the [Folder.getFiles(..)](https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/folder-object.html?highlight=getfiles#getfiles) function accepts `RegExp` objects ?

Comment: Yes, I learned this somewhere along the way (most likely from a post on ps-scripts.com) and have used a `RegExp` as a `[mask]` for the `Folder.getFiles()` method ever since.